# Image type in DICOM Standard MONOCHROME1 and MONOCHROME2

Tags: image, dicom

I have a question for image type in dicom standard. In the dicom document I found image type has five types which are :

```
MONOCHROME1
MONOCHROME2 MPEG2 -single component data
YBR_ICT
YBR_RCT
YBR_PARTIAL_420 MPEG2 -multi-component data
```

If image type in dicom file is MONOCHROME1 or MONOCHROME2, Is it compress or not compress? And What are different between two type: MONOCHROME1 or MONOCHROME2? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

`MONOCHROME1` indicates that the greyscale ranges from bright to dark with ascending pixel values, whereas `MONOCHROME2` ranges from dark to bright with ascending pixel values.

Image compression is independent of the *Photometric Interpretation (0028,0004)* attribute. Compression is instead given by the *Transfer Syntax UID (0002,0010)* attribute.

You can read more in the short DICOM introduction [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150920230923/http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/mricro/dicom/index.html).

Comment: The DICOM [link](http://www.mccauslandcenter.sc.edu/crnl/dicom/index.html) is dead

Comment: Thanks, Nick. Apparently the page has been down since 2016... I have redirected to the latest available archived version of the page.

Answer (score 2):

There are several more types of Photometric Interpretations. As Anders said, that has no relation with the Transfer syntax.

I assume you will need some additional information about **Photometric Interpretation**, since you will need that in order to be able to display the Dicom image.

I would suggest you to have a look [here](http://www.medicalconnections.co.uk/kb/Photometric_Interpretations) and [here](http://www.dabsoft.ch/dicom/3/C.7.6.3.1.2/).